# Super simple left to right slider using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a simple content slider for some testimonials on my site. I don't need any fancy effects. All I need is to be able to show like 3 testimonials and then have arrows where you can click left and right to see more testimonials.

How can I make this happen using jquery?

This is how I have the html set up right now.

```
<div id="testimonial-rotator">
<div class="testimonial">Testimonial 1</div>
<div class="testimonial">Testimonial 2</div>
<div class="testimonial">Testimonial 3</div>
<div class="testimonial">Testimonial 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code so far? What didn't work? Can you post a live demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I don't have a jquery code right now. I just have the html set up.

Comment: Give a try then come back with your actual JavaScript code, and people  might help. Here's a plugin that does what you want http://bxslider.com/

Comment: Here is a list of 20 slider to choose from: http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/tools/awesome-jquery-sliders/

Comment: down vote for lack of effort

Answer (score 1):

you can change the class into id

```
<button id="prev" disabled="disabled">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
<hr /> 

<div id="testimonial-rotator">
    <div id="testimonial" class="first current">Testimonial 1</div>
    <div id="testimonial2">Testimonial 2</div>
    <div id="testimonial3">Testimonial 3</div>
    <div id="testimonial4" class="last">Testimonial 4</div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$('#next').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
        .next().show().addClass('current');
    if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
        $('#next').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    $('#prev').attr('disabled', null);
});

$('#prev').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
        .prev().show().addClass('current');
    if ($('.current').hasClass('first')) {
        $('#prev').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    $('#next').attr('disabled', null);
});
```

css

```css
#testimonial2, #testimonial3, #testimonial4{
    display: none;
}
```

**DEMO** : http://jsfiddle.net/ayiem999/u7Wcz/